# measure space of a sequence (demonstration)

Tags: real-analysis

Given a measure space $ \ ( \Omega , \Sigma , \mu ) $ and a sequence $A_n \in{} \Sigma $
Prove that: $ \mu
\ ( \displaystyle\cup{}_{n=1}^{ \infty }A_n ) \leq{} \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }
\mu \ ( A_n ) $

I can then generalize this proof as follows:
We define
$\displaystyle B_n= A_n \setminus \bigcup _{i=1}^{n-1} A_i$

understanding that

$\displaystyle \ (B_1 = A_1 \ )$ so that $\displaystyle B_n \in A$
$\displaystyle \bigcup _{n=1}^{ \infty} B_n = \bigcup _{n=1}^{ \infty} A_n \in A$
and the sets $\displaystyle B_n$ are disjoint two by two, therefore:

$\displaystyle \mu ( \bigcup _{n=1}^{ \infty} A_n ) = \mu ( \bigcup _{n=1}^{ \infty} B_n ) = \displaystyle\sum_{n= 1}^{ \infty } \mu ( B_n ) \leq{}  \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{ \infty} \mu \, A_n$

Comment: Where did your last equality come from? Why is $\mu(B_n) = \mu(A_n)$?

Comment: Hello, it was a transcription error, I have already corrected it.